# Complex NOT EXISTS or NOT IN Query

Tags: sql-server, not-exists

I have three main tables I'm working with. This query returns a subset of what I want

```
SELECT
    dt.DepositTypeID,
    dt.DepositTypeName AS DepositType, 
    'Total Revenues' AS TransactionGroupType,
    d.FiscalYearTypeID,
    SUM(d.DepositAmount) AS Amount
FROM
    Deposit AS d 
    INNER JOIN DepositType AS dt ON d.DepositTypeID = dt.DepositTypeID 
    INNER JOIN FiscalYearType AS fyt ON d.FiscalYearTypeID = fyt.FiscalYearTypeID
WHERE
    dt.DepositTypeID IN(1,2,4) 
    AND d.TransactionStatusTypeId = 3 --Must be approved
    AND d.IsProjectedDeposit = 0 --Must not be projected deposit
GROUP BY
    dt.DepositTypeName,
    d.FiscalYearTypeID,
    dt.DepositTypeID
ORDER BY
    dt.DepositTypeID,
    d.FiscalYearTypeID
```

Returns the subset below

```
DepositTypeID | DepositType | TransactionGroupType | FiscalYearTypeID | Amount
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1           Auction        Total Revenues           1             3434
      1           Auction        Total Revenues           3             52152
      1           Auction        Total Revenues           4             12859
      1           Auction        Total Revenues           5             542863
      1           SMIF Interest  Total Revenues           5             524586
```

Now, to complete my query, I need to extract all the DepositTypes and FiscalYearTypes that are not in there and populate the Amount with a zero.

```
DepositTypeID | DepositType | TransactionGroupType | FiscalYearTypeID | Amount
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1           Auction        Total Revenues           1             3434
      2           Reserve Sale   Total Revenues           1             0
      4           SMIF Interest  Total Revenues           1             0

      1           Auction        Total Revenues           2             0
      2           Reserve Sale   Total Revenues           2             0
      4           SMIF Interest  Total Revenues           2             0

      1           Auction        Total Revenues           3             52152
      2           Reserve Sale   Total Revenues           3             0
      4           SMIF Interest  Total Revenues           3             0

      1           Auction        Total Revenues           4             12859
      2           Reserve Sale   Total Revenues           4             0
      4           SMIF Interest  Total Revenues           4             0

      1           Auction        Total Revenues           5             542863
      2           Reserve Sale   Total Revenues           5             0
      4           SMIF Interest  Total Revenues           5             524586
```

I got some NOT EXISTS and NOT IN queries but for the life of me cannot get exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `NOT EXISTS`; it should suffice to reexamine your joins. Since you want a summary of deposits for every combination of deposit type and fiscal year type, consider a `CROSS JOIN` for the two type tables and then a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to the Deposit table. Here's how this might look:

```
-- Sample data inferred from the question:
declare @Deposit table 
(
    DepositID bigint, 
    FiscalYearTypeID bigint, 
    DepositTypeID bigint, 
    TransactionStatusTypeId bigint, 
    IsProjectedDeposit bit, 
    DepositAmount money
);
insert @Deposit values
    (1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3434),
    (2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 52152),
    (3, 4, 1, 3, 0, 12859),
    (4, 5, 1, 3, 0, 542863),
    (5, 5, 4, 3, 0, 524586),
    -- EDIT: Added this last line to test the TransactionStatusTypeId/IsProjectedDeposit restrictions.
    (6, 2, 4, 1, 0, 9000);

declare @DepositType table 
(
    DepositTypeID bigint, 
    DepositTypeName varchar(32)
);
insert @DepositType values 
    (1, 'Auction'), 
    (2, 'Reserve Sale'), 
    (4, 'SMIF Interest');

declare @FiscalYearType table (FiscalYearTypeID bigint);
insert @FiscalYearType values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

-- The query:
select
    dt.DepositTypeID,
    dt.DepositTypeName AS DepositType, 
    'Total Revenues' AS TransactionGroupType,
    fyt.FiscalYearTypeID,
    coalesce(sum(d.DepositAmount), 0) AS Amount
from
    @DepositType dt
    cross join @FiscalYearType fyt
    -- EDIT: Now applying the deposit checks as part of the join rather than in the WHERE clause.
    left join @Deposit d on 
        dt.DepositTypeID = d.DepositTypeID and
        fyt.FiscalYearTypeID = d.FiscalYearTypeID and
        d.TransactionStatusTypeId = 3 and
        d.IsProjectedDeposit = 0
where
    dt.DepositTypeID in (1, 2, 4)
group by
    dt.DepositTypeName,
    fyt.FiscalYearTypeID,
    dt.DepositTypeID
order by
    fyt.FiscalYearTypeID,
    dt.DepositTypeID;
```

Results:

```
DepositTypeID    DepositType    TransactionGroupType    FiscalYearTypeID    Amount
1                Auction        Total Revenues          1                   3434.00
2                Reserve Sale   Total Revenues          1                   0.00
4                SMIF Interest  Total Revenues          1                   0.00
1                Auction        Total Revenues          2                   0.00
2                Reserve Sale   Total Revenues          2                   0.00
4                SMIF Interest  Total Revenues          2                   0.00
1                Auction        Total Revenues          3                   52152.00
2                Reserve Sale   Total Revenues          3                   0.00
4                SMIF Interest  Total Revenues          3                   0.00
1                Auction        Total Revenues          4                   12859.00
2                Reserve Sale   Total Revenues          4                   0.00
4                SMIF Interest  Total Revenues          4                   0.00
1                Auction        Total Revenues          5                   542863.00
2                Reserve Sale   Total Revenues          5                   0.00
4                SMIF Interest  Total Revenues          5                   524586.00
```

(Edited to correct a bug in the original version of the answer.)

Comment: Almost it but not quite. I took your select query and ran it against the database and your resultset below are missing the DepositTypeID = 4 (SMIF Interest) on a few FiscalYearTypeID

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing your data, but I suspect the problem is in how I was trying to use the `WHERE` clause to limit the deposits being used. I've moved that logic into the `JOIN` instead, which should be easier to understand besides being correct. Please try the edited answer. I've called out the edits in comments.

Comment: I edited the Results above to reflect the actual set being returned by the select query

Comment: I rolled back your edit just because approving it would have undone my attempt to fix the query. Does this second version have the same defect, or is it working for you now? If there's still a problem, could you reproduce it in a SQL Fiddle or something?

Comment: You are THE MAN!!. The edited query made me get up and do my loud happy dance outside of my cubicle. Thanks Joe